# Matlab: Calculate apparent angle of horizon for points on elevation map

Tags: matlab, heightmap

I have an elevation map of a mountainous area (large 2d array with z values)

I want to know the height of the apparent horizon angle for all compass bearings for certain points on my height map.

To illustrate, this [website](http://suncurves.com/en/v/381/) has some examples of what I want.

Edit:
I've stopped trying to find a function that does this and am now writing my own.

My approach is drawing lines from my point radially, interpolating the height along those lines and then taking `max(z/r)` along each line.

If you know a function that already does this, please tell me, if not, hopefully I'll be able to upload one soon.

Comment: Why `matlab`? Have you already written some `matlab` code to solve your problem? Would you please show us what you've done so far?

Comment: So far I've looked through lots of documentation, not found anything and I was hoping someone here knew the right tool.
At the moment I'm working on using this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/49065-shadem and then iterating over all possible angles (360*90) to find out when my points are shaded and when they aren't. But there's got to be a better way of doing this.
Why matlab: it's part of a bigger physical model written in matlab, and I need to incorporate terrain shading to calculate energy flux through the surface

Comment: @Swier: It seems you haven't really thought about the mathematical background. I suggest you try to solve it for 0° first. First calculate at which angle each pixel on the line appears (trigonometric function), then take the maximum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that you have 3 matrices, `X` `Y` and `Z` and your position `(x,y,z)`, you can compute

<strike>`R = sqrt((X-x)**2 + (Y-y)**2)`</strike> (tx Daniel...)

```
R = sqrt((X-x).^2 + (Y-y).^2)
Z = (Z-z)
```

i.e., the distances from the position and the relative heights, so that

```
T = Z/R
```

is a matrix of tangents, that are a monotonous function of the visual angle from the position to the surrounding terrain.

For a given direction you can find the list of points closest on the grid with a variation of the [Bresenham algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) and finally find the highest `T` value on your list of points.

Eventually, from the list of max `T` (tangents) values for different directions you can compute the visual angles from your position.

Comment: this approach will probably result in very fast code. In matlab it is `.^` not `**`